# this.init is not a function jquery validation plugin in react app

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, reactjs

I have form in my react application, which validates via jquery validation plugin.

```
let validator = $('form').validate({
        errorClass:  'has-error',
        errorElement:'label',
    });
    validator.form();
    if ($('.has-error').length > 0) {
        $('.has-error').each(function (index) {
            $.validator().showErrors({prop:$(this).data('error')});
        });
    } else {
         /*work with data*/
}
```

All errors messages showing fine, but every time when validation triggered, I get error in console:

```
this.init is not a function
```

And link me to code in plugin script:

```
$.validator = function( options, form ) {
    this.settings = $.extend( true, {}, $.validator.defaults, options );
    this.currentForm = form;
    this.init();
};
```

How can I fix it?
UPD 1: below in the plugin script code i found this code:

```
$.extend( $.validator, {
//some code
prototype: {

        init: function() {
            this.labelContainer = $( this.settings.errorLabelContainer );
            this.errorContext = this.labelContainer.length && this.labelContainer || $( this.currentForm );
            this.containers = $( this.settings.errorContainer ).add( this.settings.errorLabelContainer );
            this.submitted = {};
            this.valueCache = {};
            this.pendingRequest = 0;
            this.pending = {};
            this.invalid = {};
            this.reset();
//some code
```

Maybe it fires error exception because of this init function?

Comment: Where do you define `init` method?

Comment: I don't define init method, it defined inside plugin script, see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
$.validator().showErrors({prop:$(this).data('error')});
```

`$.validator` function is a constructor so it must always be used with `new` keyword. If you call it as normal function `this` inside this function points to global `window` (or is `undefined` in `strict mode`) which doesn't have `init` method

Comment: Yes, problem was i that line. Thank you. But now I have new problem: if i get some errors, i never goes in else block, where works with form data. It's strange.